# Chrome consumes a lot of memory on page with tens of images

Tags: google-chrome, memory

I have a page with 100 images (plain HTML, no JS). Each image is 800x600, 143 Kb. Chrome consumes 220 Mb of memory for this tab. That's a lot for one simple page.

```
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(JPEG-HDR).jpg?k=0'>
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(JPEG-HDR).jpg?k=1'>
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(JPEG-HDR).jpg?k=2'>
...
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(JPEG-HDR).jpg?k99'>
```

Sample - http://jsfiddle.net/zhjnyb9t/embedded/result/. Scroll it and check the memory used.

According to Chrome Task Manager 200 (of 220) Mb are used by "Images Cache". I found the article from google developer (http://aerotwist.com/blog/one-weird-trick/), where he says that Chrome decodes each page image into the bitmap and stores it in the memory. That explains the huge memory consuming. But I dont like the idea to donwload and paint images via JS.

How can I disable the images decoding?